# Where can I set ellipsize property for ListView control?

Tags: android

In TextView control, I can set android:singleLine="true" and android:ellipsize="end" to truncate a long string,
but I don't know how to set the property for ListView control, could you help me ? Thanks!

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="This is a web This is a web This is a web This is a web I will go to school" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsizing a ListView doesn't even make any sense. Rather, you'll want to set the ellipsize attribute on any TextViews in the layout you're inflating for the list item in your Adapter.

Comment: I use     adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                  cur, cols, views); to fill in ListView

Comment: How can I set TextViews in ListView? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the adapter by doing

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
    cur, cols, views);
```

you're passing in the layout file that it's going to use to display the text.

As of SDK v17, that layout file looks like this:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
/>
```

Note that the text is not ellipsized.

Instead of passing in that layout, create your own similar layout file, with `android:ellipsize` set, and then pass in that layout to the adapter.

Make sure to use `@android:id/text1` as the `android:id` for the `TextView`, as that's what the adapter uses to find it.